# How can I check if "save as" dialogue box is in the right folder

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, directory, pyautogui

I have an automation script to download a file in a website using Selenium. I´m using PyAutoGUI to write the folder directory when the "save as" dialogue box opens. The problem is: some computers that runs this script is incredibly slow (really) and it press the "ok" button before write the correct directory and ends up saving the file in the wrong folder.

```
     pd.hotkey('ctrl', 'v')
     pd.hotkey('enter')
     time.sleep(10)
     pd.typewrite(file_name.txt)
     pd.hotkey('enter')
```

Is there a way I can check if the dialogue box is already in the right directory before gives the ok without use sleep method?

Answer (score 0):

Update: Apologies, I didn't notice the Python tag. But you may implement the same approach in python using your preferred class.
A similar class would be PyRobot.
https://github.com/chriskiehl/pyrobot

If you are expecting a very slow response.
I suggest using Robot (java.awt.Robot) because you can control the speed of typing thru robot.delay. It won't move to the next line as well, ensuring that it is able to type all characters of the file path before pressing the enter key.
I actually haven't tried PyAutoGUI but hope this helps.

```
public void main() throws Exception {
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    typeText("C:/file/path/TESTING.txt");
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
}

public void typeText(String strValue) throws Exception {
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    for (int idx = 0; idx < strValue.length(); idx++) {
        char chr = strValue.charAt(idx);
        if (chr == ':') {
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);  
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SEMICOLON);  
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SEMICOLON);  
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
        } else {
            if (!Character.isAlphabetic(chr)) {
                robot.keyPress(chr);
                robot.keyRelease(chr);
            } else {
                String code = "VK_" + String.valueOf(chr).toUpperCase();
                Field f = KeyEvent.class.getField(code);
                int keyEvent = f.getInt(null);
                if (String.valueOf(chr).equals(String.valueOf(chr).toUpperCase())) {
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);  
                    robot.keyPress(keyEvent);
                    robot.keyRelease(keyEvent);
                    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
                } else {
                    robot.keyPress(keyEvent);
                    robot.keyRelease(keyEvent);
                }
            }
        }
        robot.delay(500);
    }
}
```